# Start Flash Banner Below Fold When User Scrolls Down

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, flash, dhtml

I want to have a flash banner start playing once it becomes visible below the fold.

When the visitor scrolls down and it is viewable in the browser it starts playing.

Is this possible? I'd prefer if the solution was outside of flash but just want it to work. Currently the banner does not replay itself so it is playing to the end before it becomes visible. If it could load or start playing once its viewable that would solve the problem.

I know lazyloader can load images after you scroll down and facebook comments load once you scroll down but could you do the same thing with anything? in particular a flash banner.

Update: I've now the has priority paramter and can't get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.loop = "true";
            params.hasPriority = "false";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "flash";
            swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "1000", "300", "10.1.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>

        <div id="myAlternativeContent">
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use param "hasPriority" when embeding. Here is help for this parameter: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-8000.html

Another approach is by using JavaScript. There is jQuery plugin for that that draws objects when they appear in viewport: [jQuery Bullseye](http://static.pixeltango.com/jQuery/Bullseye/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it with SWFobject and just embedding it and can't get it to work. Here's SWF
<script type="text/javascript" src="/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var flashvars = {};
   var params = {};
   params.loop = "true";
   params.hasPriority = "false";
   var attributes = {};
   attributes.id = "flash";
   swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "1000", "300", "10.1.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
  </script>

Comment: Try removing quotes from around "false". In JavaScript (same like in AS) false with quotes is interpreted as string value but not a Boolean.

Comment: Rytis thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it still doesn't work. Could the flash itself have code that makes it start playing automatically on page load?

Comment: No, there is no way to detect that in Flash player. Except you can use  ExternalInterface to query with JavaScript if Flash object is displayed in viewport (you would have to do size and position calculation yourself).

I added a new solution with jQuery plugin that does things nicely.